# Who is murdering people in Smoke and Mirrors?

Tags: plot-explanation, smoke-and-mirrors

In the end of the Spanish movie [*Smoke & Mirrors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_%26_Mirrors_(2016_film)) we see the lawyer and that tall broker guy killed in their homes.

Who murders them and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spanish movie Smoke & Mirrors is based on true events. The men who acted as straw men in exchange for an economic consideration, Casturelli and Pinaud in the movie, existed in real life. They were called Jean Henry and Jack Pierre Aberlé. 
They were Swiss nationals and both died in odd circumstances.

Jean Henry was an alcoholic fireman. He was found dead with a bullet in his head
in his Geneva apartment in 1996, before the Swiss police questioned him to the fraud. the Swiss police claimed that he had committed suicide. Six months later,
Jack Pierre Aberlé who had become beggar, was found dead and half naked on the bed of his room of a hostel, the Mont Blanc Hostel, in Geneva. In is hostel prostitutes and beggars were usually staying.
Jack Pierre Aberlé have been held for several weeks in several hospitals and clinics in Geneve. Allegedly, He suffered a heart attack. The hotel staff assured the Swiss police that They had seen nothing unusual. After post-mortem examination, the Swiss police reported that Aberlé had died a natural death.

Aberlé was a representative for some Paesa's several companies and a front man for Roldán. After the case of Roldán came to light, Aberlé broke off relations with Paesa. He felt he was fooled or deceived. This dispute and some veiled threat of Paesa let out the rumor that the spy got him out of the way because Aberlé had compromising information about Paesa.

Finally, everything that happened earlier was seen as a urban legend because the judicial police argued that the conspiracy theory was wrong.

Furthermore, in this case there were others straw men (Jorge Esparza Martin, Claude Roland Costa-Curta...) who weren't found dead.

The film shows those deaths, but It does not explain them, suggesting It could be true that Paesa was responsible for the deaths.

[El País](https://elpais.com/diario/2010/02/14/domingo/1266123153_850215.html)

> Los testaferros Jean Henry, un bombero suizo alcoholizado, y Jack
>   Pierre Aberlé, un tipo que acabó de indigente, murieron como dignos
>   personajes de novela. Uno se reventó la cabeza de un disparo y el
>   cuerpo del otro apareció semidesnudo sobre la cama de un hostal para
>   vagabundos en Ginebra.

[El País](https://elpais.com/diario/1997/02/27/espana/856998015_850215.html)

> Jack Pierre Aberlé, uno de los tres testaferros suizos que utilizó
>   Luis Roldán para vaciar sus cuentas suizas, en las que ocultaba 1.605
>   millones de pesetas, murió el pasado mes de enero en un hotel de
>   Ginebra (Suiza). Fuentes de la Policía Judicial helvética señalaron
>   ayer que la muerte de Aberlé fue por causas naturales y que no se ha
>   abierto ninguna investigación.Aberlé falleció en una habitación del
>   hotel Mont Blanc, un establecimiento en el que residía desde hacía
>   años. Su cadáver fue encontrado por personal del mencionado centro
>   hotelero. El testaferro de Roldán había permanecido ingresado durante
>   varias semanas en distintos sanatorios y clínicas de Ginebra donde se
>   intentaba recuperar de una grave enfermedad. Estaba separado y era
>   padre de un hijo.

[El País](https://elpais.com/diario/1997/10/07/espana/876175223_850215.html)

> El notario Jaime García Rosado admitió ayer ante el tribunal que juzga
>   el caso Roldán que Agustín Guardia Palau, ex asesor fiscal y ex
>   abogado del procesado, pudo ser la persona que condujo en 1990 a su
>   despacho a Jean Henry, uno de los testaferros suizos utilizados cuatro
>   años después Luis Roldán para ocultar los 1.700 millones de pesetas
>   que tenía en un banco de Suiza.Guardia, que lleva la defensa de Blanca
>   Rodríguez-Porto, esposa de Roldán, para la que se piden cinco años de
>   cárcel, no acudió a la vista, en la que su nombre fue pronunciado por
>   los fiscales en varias ocasiones. Roland Costacurta, otro testaferro
>   de la trama suiza de Roldán, declaró a la Justicia helvética que había
>   trabajado anteriormente para "la inmobiliaria Guardia". Guardia ha
>   negado a este periódico conocer a Henry y tener relación con
>   Costacurta.

[El País](https://elpais.com/diario/1997/09/26/espana/875224817_850215.html)

> Jorge Esparza Martín, ex director comercial de Huarte, fue quien
>   introdujo en su empresa a los propietarios de tres sociedades fantasma
>   que facturaron a Hasa-Huarte 2.565 millones mediante facturas falsas
>   que sirvieron para camuflar el pago de comisiones ilegales, según
>   manifestó ayer Ildefonso Aguilar Gangoso, consejero delegado de la
>   citada compañía, ante el tribunal que juzga el caso. El tribunal
>   pedirá a Interpol que localice el domicilio de Francisco Paesa para
>   citarle de nuevo como testigo... Aguilar dijo que "no le consta" que Huarte 
>   pagara comisiones ilegales al clan Roldán, y al igual que su ex
>   presidente, Mario Caprile, citó a Alfonso Ochoa de Olza, un
>   administrativo de la constructora ya fallecido, para asegurar que fue
>   este último quien "contabilizó las facturas de estas sociedades, y las
>   abonó.

[El hombre de las mil caras by Manuel Cerdán: Jack Pierre Aberlé](https://books.google.es/books?id=Du-0DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT307&lpg=PT307&dq=Jack%20Pierre%20Aberl%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=oIcv5n5quq&sig=Qn-oTXjQcrAkC0YRvg_GliUrH9c&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqm5no2sndAhUNz4UKHRRaBnoQ6AEwBnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Jack%20Pierre%20Aberl%C3%A9&f=false)

[El hombre de las mil caras by Manuel Cerdán: Jorge Esparza](https://books.google.es/books?id=Du-0DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT96&lpg=PT96&dq=Jorge%20Esparza%20paesa&source=bl&ots=oIcv5nejut&sig=PHOIc5fq5yCLgTS361e26k6h_Po&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi896nf-cndAhVHlxoKHfoqBE8Q6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Esparza&f=false)